How to Apply IGraph/M For Weighted Betweenness in a Directed Graph
I've written the following code and have two questions:
(1) How can I insert weights (how to code them) to the edges in this directed multigraph?
(2) How can I compare IGBetweenness with the weights to Mathematica's BetweennessCentrality (which I understand ignore weighted edges)?
Needs["IGraphM`"]
IGVersion[]
edges = {S1 -> F1, S1 -> F1, S1 -> F1, S1 -> F1, S1 -> S2, S1 -> S2, 
   S1 -> S2, S1 -> S3, S1 -> S3, S3 -> S1, S3 -> S1, S3 -> S1, 
   S3 -> S1, S1 -> F3, S2 -> S1, S2 -> F5, S2 -> F6, S3 -> F4, 
   S3 -> S1, S5 -> S3, S5 -> S3, S5 -> S3, S5 -> S3, S5 -> S3};
g = Graph[edges];
Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> Automatic, VertexSize -> 0.35, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> 11, BaseStyle -> {Arrowheads -> 0.02}]
SortBy[{VertexList[g], IGBetweenness[g]}\[Transpose], N@*Last] // 
  Reverse;
TableForm[%]
SortBy[{VertexList[g], BetweennessCentrality[g]}\[Transpose], 
   N@*Last] // Reverse;
TableForm[%]


All IGraph/M functions that consider edge weights will take them from the EdgeWeight edge annotation/property.
Example of adding this annotation/property:
Graph[{1<->2, 2<->3, 1<->3}, EdgeWeight -> {2.0, 0.1, 1.5}]

IGBetweenness interprets edge weights as edge lengths during the shortest path calculation. IGBetweenness does support multigraphs, and will correctly choose the shorter parallel edge.
The very first example in the Basic Usage section of the IGraph/M documentation illustrates precisely computing weighted betweenness. Please do have a look at the documentation.
